# NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, decoradores

Tengo un problema con un decorador en python3, el decorador lo utilizo en una clase, para manipular una base de datos, el error es el siguiente:

> Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "BankPy.py", line 121, in <lambda>
    Button(register_frame, text = 'Login', command = lambda:self.set_admin(user.get(), password.get()
  File "BankPy.py", line 57, in connect_database
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect('database/Bank-Data')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

> Estructura del decorador:

```
def database_managment(function):
        def connect_database(*args):
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect('database/Bank-Data')
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            function(*args)
            self.connection.commit()
            self.connection.close()

        return connect_database
```

Lo utilizo para decorar métodos y cuando llamo a los métodos siempre sale el mismo Error

**De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cómo estás.

El error está en que estás mezclando dos maneras de definir los decoradores en Python.

1) Es utilizando una clase (en este caso usar "self" tiene completo sentido y es muy útil).

2) Definiendo una función. Esta es la que estás usando y no tiene sentido utilizar "self" ya que no existe ningún objeto ni clase.

Te recomiendo revises este link: [Decoradores](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html)

Básicamente la solución sería borrar self.

Ahora, creería que necesitas para el cursor al método, para que lo puedas utilizar. Para hacer esto hay muchas formas. Una forma sencilla es cambiar la definición de cada función agregando un argumento que haga referencia al cursor. Te doy un ejemplo de esto:

```
@database_managment
def select_all_towns(limit, db_cursor=None):
    db_cursor.execute("select * from mi_tabla")
    for row in db_cursor:
            print (row)
```

Esta es una función ejemplo que hace uso del decorador. Como ves solo le agrego un argumento al final que hace referencia al cursor. Lo asigno como nulo por defecto para no tener que preocuparme de este cursor cuando la llame.

El decorador quedaría así:

```
def database_managment(function):
        def connect_database(*args):
            connection = sqlite3.connect('database/Bank-Data')
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            function(*args, db_cursor=cursor)
            connection.commit()
            connection.close()

        return connect_database
```

Eso sería todo.
Te felicito por la idea de los decoradores para la base de datos, es bastante ingeniosa y elegante.

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Cuando llames a la función no intentes pasar el argumento "db_cursor", este se carga automáticamente con el wrapper de tu decorador.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta por sí misma es la siguiente, dentro del contexto del wrapper no existe ninguna definición para la variable `self` ya que ningún parámetro se llama explícitamente así, el decorador no asume por default la existencia de ningún parámetro y por lo tanto no estás mapeando adecuadamente lo dicho.

Por lo que veo, esperas que las funciones decoradas hagan uso de la variable `self.connection` o en realidad de `self.cursor` la cuestión es, que para la función no existen tampoco, porque dichas variables no existen dentro del contexto de la función misma.

```py
def foo(f):
    def bar(*args):
        variable = [] # Esta variable existe dentro del contexto de bar, pero no dentro del de la función f
        f(*args)
        print(variable) # Por lo tanto nunca se ve modificada a sí misma dentro de la otra función.
```

Pero resolviendo el problema, necesitas un decorador que te permita establecer conexiones a la base sin gestionarla directamente, debido a que el parámetro inicial de todos los métodos en una clase, por default y de manera implicita es la instancia misma de la clase, necesitarás gestionar parámetros posicionales (para el `self`) y kwargs para los demás.

tu decorador quedaría del siguiente modo:

```py
def database_connection(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('base.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        kwargs['cursor'] = cursor
        function(*args, **kwargs)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
    return wrapper
```

El proceso del wrapper es esencialmente el siguiente:
- Genera una conexión a la base
- Crea una instancia de cursor para las operaciones
- Agrega la instancia del cursor a la lista de kwargs
- Llama a la función decorada
- Efectúa los cambios y cierra la conexión.

La desventaja es que con este medio debes manejar mandatoriamente un parámetro *cursor* en cada una de las funciones decoradas y eso le resta cierta flexibilidad a cambio de no gestionar la conexión a la base directamente.

La clase y cada uno de sus métodos debería replicar el siguiente ejemplo:

```py
class Foo(object):
    @database_connection
    def bar(self, cursor):
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLE')
```

De este modo el parámetro self pasa automáticamente dentro de los argumentos posicionales y el cursor dentro de los argumentos *etiquetados* (No conozco una buena traducción para *keyword arguments*)

El código completo del decorador y la clase de ejemplo por si quieres hacer una prueba es el siguiente:

```py
import sqlite3

def database_connection(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('base.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        kwargs['cursor'] = cursor
        function(*args, **kwargs)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
    return wrapper


class Foo(object):
    @database_connection
    def crear_tabla(self, table_name: str, cursor: sqlite3.Cursor):
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE {} (id INT)'.format(table_name))


f = Foo()
f.crear_tabla('Tabla')
f.crear_tabla(table_name='OtraTabla')
```